# Drupal 7 imagecache effects not rendering in Chrome or Safari but ok in Firefox

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created some content types displayed as Views blocks. I've added an imagefield which should display an imagecache style with resize effect (upscaling is also ticked). These show up just fine in Firefox but the imagecache effects are totally lost in both Chrome and Safari. Anyone come across this before?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inagecahe itself is absolutely browser non dependant, so sounds more like browser caching issue. Just clear cache in Chrome and Safari and reload page a few times.

Comment: Thanks I had cleared the caches of both browsers over and over again. I discovered,, after much hair pulling that it was my Zen theme which has img {width: 100%;} set as a default - this was preventing the images from rendering in those browsers to the width I had configured in imagestyles. Once I removed that bit of css - voila! the images came up perfectly in Chrome and Safari.